# Disable right click on browser's back and forward button

Tags: javascript, browser, navigation, browser-history

Is there a way to disable the right click for the back and forward button of the browser using javascript or silverlight? I don't want the users to access the list of histories shown via context menu when you right click on the buttons. I just want the user to be able to left click on the back and forward button to navigate.

Comment: Would you permit the user to open Minesweeper while he is browsing your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Pekka's answer.  The only suggestion I would make it to open your application/page/whatever in a new window, using the javascript window.open method, and specify the parameters of the new window so the address bar etc are hidden.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to disable the right click for the back and forward button of the browser using javascript or silverlight?

No, definitely not. This is outside web pages' control.